# Calculating the branching ratio of higgs for decay to two photons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, higgs

I need to use the three lowest order Feynman diagrams to first calculate the squared matrix element to put into Fermi's golden rule formula and then from there get the branching ratio of higgs decays into 2 photons.

Comment: ...What's the question?

Comment: Hi user24218, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a site for conceptual questions about physics, not general homework help (and even if this isn't homework-related, you haven't actually asked anything, like zhermes said). If you can edit your question to ask about the specific physics concept that is giving you trouble, I'll be happy to reopen it. See our [FAQ#questions] and [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more information.

Comment: @user24218: Please be specific as to which steps you need help in.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: THe question is not clear, but I think it's an important one. Especially with the interesting (minor) excess observed for the Higgs $\longrightarrow$ 2 photons decay rate, at the LHC.

Comment: @Siva oh, of course, I never said otherwise. But still, it needs to be an actual question.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, I made that comment since I saw the question closed for reasons "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors...". I now guess that the category of closure is an administrative technicality, not necessarily indicating the exact reason why the question was closed :-)

Comment: @Siva yeah, the close reasons we have to choose from are not very precise. In this case I picked "too localized" because that's my default for when someone posts their task without showing any effort to work through it on their own part, but "not a real question" would probably have been a better choice.